# How to string replace and string re arrange

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that returns `04/01/2014` , my problem now is how can I change it using jquery so that the string will become `2014-04-01` ?

```
var stringDate = '04/01/2014';
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. It has to do with JavaScript strings.

Comment: Where does your string come from? Is it generated from a Date() object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split a JavaScript string into parts delimited by a pattern (in your case, `/`), and you can combine them back together however you like using another delimiter.

For instance:

```
var str = "04/01/2014";
var parts = str.split("/");
var result = parts[2] + "-" + parts[0] + "-" + parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

make a `DateTime()` variable then you can manipiulate it how you want